# Using the Map function to remove a object from an activerecord::relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a complicated scope where I'm grabbing a checklist.  In this checklist there are a bunch of tasks under difference categories.  I only want the completed checklists, but some of the checklists will be complete without every category being finished.  So I need to be able to check if each column is needed before checking if the column has anything in it.  Here's my example.

```
scope :complete, lambda {|check_lists| check_lists.map do |check_list|
    not_complete = false

    if check_list.event.booking.video_for_event?
        if check_list.raw_footage_user_id.blank? && check_list.raw_footage_check.blank? then not_complete = true end    
    end

    if check_list.event.booking.eblast_not_blank?
      # more checking...
    end

    if check_list.event.booking.on_site_not_blank?
      # more checking...
    end

    if not_complete then reject end
end } #If videos, verify video items. if eblasts, verify eblast items, etc...
```

So basically I need to know how to finish it off by removing non_complete objects from the array being mapped out.

Comment: You should consider also seeking advice on simplifying your scope. That is *really* ugly.

Comment: Actually I tried to type out an example of what I'm doing and left very basic commands to get the point across.  All I really need is how to get it out of my array.  If your going to comment at least make it constructive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand clearly you want only the completed checklists

Basically you must return the checklist when it's true and nil when it's not, then eliminate the nils in resulting array with compact... which is the work of select

```
checklists.map do |checklist| 
  # ....
  checklist unless not_completed
end.compact
```

or more concisely :

```
checklists.select do |checklist| 
  # ....
  !not_completed
end
```